# Варианты теста - как представить в БД?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Нужно создать программу для тестирования. Суть в том, что есть список дисциплин, по каждой имеется несколько тестов, в каждом тесте имеется несколько вариантов, в которых, собственно, уже находятся задания.

Если дисциплину и тест было легко представить связью М-М через доп. таблицу, то что делать с вариантами теста, ума не приложу.

Создать отдельную таблицу для вариантов? Тогда варианты будут нумероваться непрерывно, и для каждого теста невозможно будет создать варианты 1, 2 и т. д.

Если в этой таблице создать отдельный столбец для номера варианта в тесте, то тогда также придётся для каждого теста создать столбец с числом вариантов и проверять, нет ли превышения этого числа.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Дисциплина (N:N) Тест (1:N) ВариантТеста (N:N) Задание. *Тогда варианты будут нумероваться непрерывно* Сфига бы?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно варианты хранить в XML.

Как раз отпадет надобность в доп. сущности+ такая реализация с виду не противоречит никаким правилам.

Comment: А правило 1 НФ `Все столбцы являются обычными.`? «Обычность» всех столбцов таблицы означает, что в таблице нет «скрытых» компонентов, которые могут быть доступны только в вызове некоторого специального оператора.